# easiest way to implement a shift register in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to implement a data structure similar to a shift register, basically a shift register should have a fixed length (L) and should have a function to mange the input to this register (New_Input), the new input will be in the first cell of the shift register and the previous element will be shifted one cell forward. When the register is full and a new element is added it will shift all the element such that the element in the last cell will be thrown (out of our concern).

My idea to implement such things is by using a dictionary that contain those element such that the keys are the order of this dictionary.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Sounds like you want a [double-ended queue](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque). Push to the front and drop the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python already contains this data structure as [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.deque):

```
>>> import collections
>>> c = collections.deque([], 2)
>>> c.extend('a')
>>> c.extend('b')
>>> c.extend('c')
>>> c
deque(['b', 'c'], maxlen=2)
```

Comment: what i need to do if i have 2 variables for each element in this structure 
c=collections.deque([[ ]*2], L)

c.extend(['a','b']) is this valid ?

Comment: If each element in the queue is more complicated, then pack it into a [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) or `dict`

Comment: @phihag: I would have used `.append(elem)` which would preserve any arbitrary type that `elem` refers to.

Comment: @AliJawadFahs Note that `deque([[ ]*2], L)` does not make sense. `[] * 2` is still `[]`. If you want to initialize the queue with an "empty" list of length `L`, you could try e.g. `[None] * L`

Comment: >>>import collections
>>>a={}
>>>a[1]=2
>>>c = collections.deque([], 2)
>>>c.extend(a.items())
>>>a[1]=3
>>>c.extend(a.items())
>>>a[1]=4
>>>c.extend(a.items())

>>>print c worked as charm, thanks bro